# How can I estimate robust standard errors for robust estimators? R

Tags: r, regression, robust, robust-standard-error

I am doing a robust regression and I want to estimate robust standard errors for my regression. I do know how to do a robust regression in R and how to estimate a robust standard errors for a  `lm` or `nls` model. I read a [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://feb.kuleuven.be/public/u0017833/PDF-FILES/robse.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiKxZaY6uz8AhXE66QKHZIvARUQFnoECAgQBg&usg=AOvVaw0WY2gLqWNLDe1poMBC4WWs) where it explains the theory but is there a function in R that is supposed to do what I want?

I tried to use the function to estimate robust std. errors `nlshc()` and I applied it to the robust regression function `nlrob()` and it gives me back some estimates but I think that the compatibility of these functions is pure luck. I don't think it replicates what the paper propose.

Comment: The summary output of ```lmrob``` in package ```robustbase``` provides standard errors, doesn't it?

Comment: I suppose it does but they are standard errors for a robust regression, I'm interested in robust standard errors for a robust regression.  Robust standard errors takes into account for heteroscedasticity, robust regression takes into account for outliers. Standard errors for robust regression are just the errors of the parameters obtained taking into account only for outliers

Comment: Robust standard errors for robust regression are robust against heteroscedasticity, autocorrelation and outliers. Standard errors for robust regression are robust against outliers.

Comment: The standard errors reported by ```lmrob``` will take into account everything that is taken into account by ```lmrob``` itself. The standard errors can't be more robust than the estimators themselves.

Comment: Of course they can, have a look at the paper I linked in the question

Comment: Interesting... this is a 2003 paper that they seemingly never have published in a journal. This doesn't make me expect with high subjective probability that this is implemented anywhere. You may write to Christophe Croux and ask him about it; he is pretty approachable as far as I know. https://www.edhec.edu/en/research-and-faculty/faculty/professors-and-researchers/christophe-croux

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll surely write him about it

Comment: aside: statsmodels has an open issue with some more references https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1379 (no code yet)